# search by text and update Observable<Array[]> Angular 7

Tags: angular, filter, rxjs, observable, angular7

i need an help.
I'm new of Angular, and i'm using Angular 7, latest release.

**So my Html code:**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" (input)="onSearchChange($event.target.value)" placeholder="Search serial...">
```

**My component.ts**

```
  onSearchChange(searchValue: string) {
    //alert(searchValue);
    console.log(searchValue);
    this.filteredItems = this.listaTest; //uno un array di appoggio per la ricerca real-time
    this.filteredItems.subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.filteredItems = response.filter(x => x.seriale.startsWith(searchValue));
        });
  }
```

**My `<ul>` list:**

```
<ul class="list-group" style="width:80%; margin:0 auto; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 2%;">
  <li *ngFor="let item of filteredItems | async" class="list-group-item">{{item.seriale}}
  <button style="float:right;">{{item.seriale}}Download certificati</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

my target is update the `<ul>` list when the user search, on realtime. 
So i've tried with an Array, not Observable and i've just push and remove and done. 
But, with the Observable, how i can update on real time the  list ? And filtering the same ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the ts file, you can combine search stream and list stream to get a result stream.

```
// a stream of search keyword
const search$ = new Subject();

const refineSearch$ = search$.pipe(
  // you can filter out empty string if you want
  filter(keyword => keyword !== ''),
  // avoid to many work by debounceTime
  debounceTime(500),
)

// here use of for demonstration
// if your list is changing over time
// its should be a list of stream
const list$ = of(aListOfItem);

const result$ = combineLatest(refineSearch$, list$)
  .pipe(map(([keyword, list]) => getSearchResult(keyword, list)));

function getSearchResult(keyword, list) {
  // implement your filter
  // return an array
}
```

In the template, the input event will simply make a next value to search stream.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" (input)="search$.next($event.target.value)" placeholder="Search serial...">
```

The ul is not much changed, just replace the filteredItems to result$ stream

```
<ul class="list-group" style="width:80%; margin:0 auto; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 2%;">
  <li *ngFor="let item of result$ | async" class="list-group-item">{{item.seriale}}
  <button style="float:right;">{{item.seriale}}Download certificati</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```